# Characters doesn't show as I type in textarea on iOS with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, textarea, ionic3

I am using a `<textarea>` with Ionic 3 but when I type in, only the first character is displayed, not the rest.

Only wait to display them is to close the keyboard, scroll the page and come back.

Here is my code:

```
//view
        <textarea class="textarea" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" placeholder="Message" [(ngModel)]="message"></textarea>

//css
    textarea.textarea {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0.55px solid #c8c7cc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 4px 45px 4px 4px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
      }
```

I guess it is a refreshing issue but don't know how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic has its own version of `textarea` called `ion-textarea`:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/

It is normally used in the context of a list to structure the content:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea placeholder="Enter a description"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This should also avoid your input problem.

Comment: The problem remains... `<ion-textarea class="textarea" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" placeholder="Message"></ion-textarea>`

Comment: You shouldn't need that extra class.

What happens if you type two small "i" next to each other, do you see both or only one?

Comment: My mistake, it was just another class of my css affecting `:before`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help. Accept my answer if it is the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you can use , use this code.
I think textarea doesn't work in ionic well.